# React Native open iOS App Notifications setting

Tags: ios, react-native

[image]

I am able to open the above screen with `Linking.openURL('app-settings:')`.

Is there a way to go a layer deeper and open the `Notifications` setting instead (see below)?

I have searched for some answers and tried `Linking.openURL('app-settings:2')`, `Linking.openURL('app-settings:{2}')` and `Linking.openURL('app-settings:NOTIFICATIONS')` without luck.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=<bundle_id>')
```

works for me. iOS 14.7.1

Answer (score 2):

You can now use this instead:

```js
Linking.openSettings();
```

This will open your apps settings, which should have the "Notifications" setting as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this syntax:

`Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID')`

Complete list of options:
https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/b7019c22fc3152a0b2fe

Dunno why the `root=` is not needed...

Comment: Working for me on iOS 14.5

Answer (score 0):

react native 0.72.5

iOS 16.6.1

```
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=<bundle_id>')
```

working